# How do you get gold in kittens game?

Tags: kittens-game

The Griffins just came by and I want to trade with them. I only need gold and 1000 Catpower, but I just need the gold. For the Catpower, I know what to do.
I just need to get a lot of warehouses and barns. So... I just need help with the gold.

Answer (score 1):

From [the wiki](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Gold):

> Production
>
> After the Gold Ore upgrade, Smelters produce 0.001 gold per
> tick in addition to 0.02 iron for each 0.05 wood and 0.1 minerals.
>
> After the Geodesy upgrade, geologists produce 0.0008 gold per tick.
>
> After the Mining Drill upgrade, this amount is increased by 0.0005 per
> tick.
>
> After the Unobtainium Drill upgrade, this amount is increased by
> 0.0005 per tick. In Iron Will mode, hunters can find gold.